# Android XML Parsing Error - "Couldn't open .../directory/container.xml"

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, android-sdcard

I am trying to parse an XML file that is sitting on the sdCard on my android device.

This piece of code -

```
SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
sp.parse("/mnt/sdcard/Speedr/pg55/META-INF/container.xml", xmlHandler);
```

Outputs this error -

> Couldn't open /mnt/sdcard/Speedr/pg55/META-INF/container.xml
>
> Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: /mnt/sdcard/Speedr/pg55/META-INF/container.xml

For the sake of simplicity, I have changed the sp.parse() location, but this is exactly what is being handed to the method in the real code. I have also taken away the try/catch brackets that should surround it.

The file is most definitely there, I can see it if I browse to it on my Phone or Computer and the location is also correct since it is not giving me a FileNotFound error.

I originally built this code in standalone Java and have been trying to implement it onto an Android device and ran into this error. The error log really is less than helpful.

I would greatly appreciate any help I can get from anyone here.

Comment: Would you please share the stack trace, that would help us figure out where / why that problem could be originated.

Comment: This is my problem, that is the only error that is caught by the try/catch brackets is what I have shown you, it is giving me nothing else. Any errors after that are simple a result of not being able to read the file.

Comment: Actually i am interested in this error's stack trace. You should copy it from LogCat (or if you don't use it, just run ddms while debugging the application on your device). Please see my post, might help you get into the right direction.

Comment: Actually when I went looking again I found it had a  java.net.MalformedURLException, I have edited the main comment to show this. Maybe this will point closer to the problem? Thanks for your help by the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure, that you have the following permission included in your `androidManifest.xml`, in case that you'd like to modify your xml, or save an other:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and change your code to:

```
final File xml = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().
        getAbsolutePath() + "Speedr/pg55/META-INF/container.xml");
sp.parse(xml, xmlHandler);
```

This way you're passing a file to the parser, so you don't need to specify the `file://` protocol. 
Try not using static path. The external storage path changes based on devices.
Using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` is the good practice.

You might also want to check whether the `xml` file exists, etc., but basically this is the way it should work.

Please see [this article about using external storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal) on Android Developers, for further checks about the storage state, etc.

Comment: Nope, changing the line to sp.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Speedr/pg55/META-INF/container.xml", xmlHandler);
  gives the same error.

Comment: you should pay attention to the line above, it is creating a new file. If you'd like to stick to the static path, you should specify the `file://` protocol in front of your path string (that's why it gives you `MalformedUrlException`).

Comment: i'm glad to hear, happy coding further! :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you enable or add SD Card permissions in the manifest?

Comment: I have the permissions android.permission.INTERNET and android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE enabled. I believe this is all that is needed as I am already able to load a .txt file without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify protocol like http, ftp, file etc. Here you are accessing it from sdcard so it would be `"file://"` before whole path.

Now modify your code snippet with this,

```
SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
sp.parse("file://" + "/mnt/sdcard/Speedr/pg55/META-INF/container.xml", xmlHandler);
```